# Existence of Solution to a Linear System of Equations Including Characteristic Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a real $n\times n $ matrix, and let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. For an arbitrary $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$, does the equation
\begin{align}
Ax = \lambda x + b
\end{align}
have a solution $x$ (not necessarily unique)? Is it possible that it has no solutions?

My attempt: We can re-write the equation as $(A - \lambda I) x = b$, which is a linear system. Since $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, we know $A - \lambda I$ is singular. On the other hand, when a linear system of equations have a singular matrix coefficient, then it will have either no solution, or an
infinite number of solutions. However, I wonder if some other properties of $A - \lambda I$ (i.e., the fact that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$) will rule out the no-solution possibility? My goal is to prove that this system always has a solution.

Comment: No, a simple example is $A=I$ and $b$ nonzero. (in fact there is always such $b$ for which the equation will have no solution)

Comment: Nice example. You are right.

Comment: The equation has a (non-trivial) solution only if $b$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.